# unable to access hard drive with Ubuntu as my only operating system

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I can't access my internal hard drive. Ubuntu, recently installed,WITHOUT

Windows. Receive the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/magal/D0CAEAF7CAEAD8AC: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/magal/D0CAEAF7CAEAD8AC"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's work for you:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

Then restart ubuntu.